# how to make Telegram bot dynamic keyboardbutton in python every button on one row

Tags: python

I want to make a keyboard button(`replykeyboardmarkup`) that reads data from the database and every button on every row of the keyboard to show.

I want to create a custom keyboard in telegram bot. For example: We have an array of strings that we get from the database. How we can push data from array to InlineKeyboardMarkup? Dynamic, responsive button.

What can I do?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 23):

In the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) they didn't mention about how to deal with dynamic [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton). But there is a way to do this kind of things using [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery). In the following example assume *stringList* variable will be hold the database query results, to do this I am using *stringList* as a [Pyton Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) and [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) which is implement for the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

```
stringList = {"Name": "John", "Language": "Python", "API": "pyTelegramBotAPI"}
```

Let's create buttons according to *stringList* by importing types from telebot. In here *callback_data* fulfill with a List which helps us to pass the data from button to query handlers. There is a limitation, if your *callback_data* is more than 64 bytes [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) will generate *BUTTON_DATA_INVALID* respond. Please refer more about [Markup Errors](https://github.com/mkotb/Telegram-Errors/wiki/Markup-Errors) to avoid those kind of exceptions.

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

for key, value in stringList.items():
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=value,
                                          callback_data="['value', '" + value + "', '" + key + "']"),
               types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=crossIcon,
                                          callback_data="['key', '" + key + "']"))
```

Below image is the result of above code.

[image: Result of the InlineKeyboardButton]

I am using this cross icon to show you how to delete dynamic button and how to edit the [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) with removing that dynamic button. As you can see (above code) there are two [CallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery) which handle the first button and the cross button.

You can capture first button's *callback_data* in following code lines.

```
if (call.data.startswith("['value'")):
    print(f"call.data : {call.data} , type : {type(call.data)}")
    print(f"ast.literal_eval(call.data) : {ast.literal_eval(call.data)} , type : {type(ast.literal_eval(call.data))}")
    valueFromCallBack = ast.literal_eval(call.data)[1]
    keyFromCallBack = ast.literal_eval(call.data)[2]
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=True,
                              text="You Clicked " + valueFromCallBack + " and key is " + keyFromCallBack)
```

There are two print statements to see exactly which type of data that we are going to handle. First print statement shows us the string type List when we click the first button of *John*.

```
call.data : ['value', 'John', 'Name'] , type : <class 'str'>
```

We are almost closer to the solution, but with the string type List. I found a solution to convert string type List into the normal List by referring answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list). Python [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast)(Abstract Syntax Trees) is the module which representation of the abstract syntactic structure of source code. Using [ast.literal_eval()](http://representation%20of%20the%20abstract%20syntactic%20structure%20of%20source%20code) we can get the following output from the second print statement.

```
ast.literal_eval(call.data) : ['value', 'John', 'Name'] , type : <class 'list'>
```

Meantime display this alert as well becasue of [answerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) which we are using in the above code.

[image: Result of the answerCallbackQuery]

We can get output like this because we fill the button with List of values. Likewise you can pass the List inside *callback_data* and handle that List in *callback_query_handler*. Let's take a look at what will happens when click the cross icon.

```
if (call.data.startswith("['key'")):
    keyFromCallBack = ast.literal_eval(call.data)[1]
    del stringList[keyFromCallBack]
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                          text="Here are the values of stringList", message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          reply_markup=makeKeyboard(), parse_mode='HTML')
```

It will go to [answerCallbackQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) which start with " '[key' " and delete the [Pyton Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) by using the given key (`del stringList[keyFromCallBack]`). Let's click first cross icon see what will happen.

[image: Regenerate dynamic buttons according to the List]

First button will be disappeared because [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext) regenerate with available Dictionary details. Instead of deleting [Pyton Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) you can call some database query.

Here is the full code of the above examples.

```
import telebot
import ast
import time
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_BOT_API_KEY_HERE")

stringList = {"Name": "John", "Language": "Python", "API": "pyTelegramBotAPI"}
crossIcon = u"\u274C"

def makeKeyboard():
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    for key, value in stringList.items():
        markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=value,
                                              callback_data="['value', '" + value + "', '" + key + "']"),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=crossIcon,
                                   callback_data="['key', '" + key + "']"))

    return markup

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test'])
def handle_command_adminwindow(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                     text="Here are the values of stringList",
                     reply_markup=makeKeyboard(),
                     parse_mode='HTML')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handle_query(call):

    if (call.data.startswith("['value'")):
        print(f"call.data : {call.data} , type : {type(call.data)}")
        print(f"ast.literal_eval(call.data) : {ast.literal_eval(call.data)} , type : {type(ast.literal_eval(call.data))}")
        valueFromCallBack = ast.literal_eval(call.data)[1]
        keyFromCallBack = ast.literal_eval(call.data)[2]
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id,
                              show_alert=True,
                              text="You Clicked " + valueFromCallBack + " and key is " + keyFromCallBack)

    if (call.data.startswith("['key'")):
        keyFromCallBack = ast.literal_eval(call.data)[1]
        del stringList[keyFromCallBack]
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                              text="Here are the values of stringList",
                              message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              reply_markup=makeKeyboard(),
                              parse_mode='HTML')
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=0)
    except:
        time.sleep(10)
```

To test this code type /test command in your bot window.

Answer (score 10):

This is using **python-telegram-bot**:

If you are having a list of cities and you want to display like this:

[image: Telegram bot displaying the list of cities in a row]

```
def city(update,context):
  list_of_cities = ['Erode','Coimbatore','London', 'Thunder Bay', 'California']
  button_list = []
  for each in list_of_cities:
     button_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton(each, callback_data = each))
  reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list,n_cols=1)) #n_cols = 1 is for single column and mutliple rows
  bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Choose from the following',reply_markup=reply_markup)


def build_menu(buttons,n_cols,header_buttons=None,footer_buttons=None):
  menu = [buttons[i:i + n_cols] for i in range(0, len(buttons), n_cols)]
  if header_buttons:
    menu.insert(0, header_buttons)
  if footer_buttons:
    menu.append(footer_buttons)
  return menu
```

If you need any clarification comment below!

Comment: your script helped a lot, but I want to put this in conversationhandler , so I want to know how can i handle callback_data in this case?

Comment: Can you please help at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732090/how-to-write-dynamic-keyboard-with-conversationhandler-in-python-telegram-bot

Answer (score 3):

## use python telegram bot

```
dictionary = {"Name": "John", "Language": "Python", "API": "pyTelegramBotAPI"}

buttons = []

for key, value in dictionary.items():
    buttons.append(
    [InlineKeyboardButton(text = key, url = 'google.com')]
    )
keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)
bot.sendMessage(chat_id,text = 'f', reply_markup = keyboard)
```

Comment: How to get values as a response from pressing buttons instead of key?

Comment: Change ```dice``` with ```dict```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python-telegram-bot as library you can take a look at the his documentation [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#build-a-menu-with-buttons)

Also if you are not using that library, you could adapt that function on your code

Comment: yes iam using python-telegram-bot. 
i was learn too, but still cant find this method.

Comment: That's not included in the library. You should copy and paste and use that function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), according to this [snippets](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets),
it should be something like this

```
>>> custom_keyboard = [['top-left', 'top-right'], 
...                    ['bottom-left', 'bottom-right']]
>>> reply_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard)
>>> bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, 
...                  text="Custom Keyboard Test", 
...                  reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Note that I did not check the code. Let me Know if is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

**lib:** [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

Considering the other answers provide info about how to create and delete *InlineKeyboardButton*, following how to edit them in a "dynamic, responsive" manner using *[edit_message_reply_markup](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.edit_message_reply_markup)* method:

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from random import seed
from random import random

...

def start(bot, update):
    keyboard = [
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Click button 1", callback_data='callback_1')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Click button 1", callback_data='callback_2')]
            ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    message_reply_text = 'Click one of these buttons'
    update.message.reply_text(message_reply_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)

def press_button_callback(bot, update):
    seed(1)
    random_number = str(random())
    keyboard = [
                [InlineKeyboardButton('Click button 1' , callback_data='callback_1')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton('Click button 1 ' + random_number, callback_data='callback_2')]
            ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.callback_query.edit_message_reply_markup(reply_markup)

def create_updater():
   updater = Updater('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
   updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
   updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(press_button_callback))
   updater.dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)
return updater

...
```

Answer (score 1):

For just one button, try this -

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"chat_id":"@entropytrades", "text":"Testing", "reply_markup": {"inline_keyboard": [[{"text":"Visit Unofficed", "url": "http://unofficed.com"}]]} }'

response = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a text file, each line of which was a button.
You can just use any array like so:

```
markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
for line in open('comments.txt', encoding='utf-8').readlines():
    markup_reply.row(types.KeyboardButton(line))
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'message', reply_markup=markup_reply)
```